Question about a proof on Differential Geometry

Let $I \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ an open interval and $\alpha \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(I ; \Bbb{R}^3$) an arclength parametrized curve such that $\forall s \in I : \kappa_\alpha (s) > 0$ . Then, if the curvature and torsion of $\alpha$ are constant, $\alpha$ is an helix arc.

I am reading a proof of this but I do not understand a step. The proof proceeds by denoting $\kappa_\alpha = k \in \Bbb{R}$, $\tau_\alpha = \tau \in \Bbb{R}$ and using Frenet's relations as follows:
$$T_\alpha ' = k N_\alpha \implies T_\alpha '' = - k^2 T_\alpha + k \tau B_\alpha \implies T_\alpha ''' = -k^2 T_\alpha ' - k \tau N_\alpha = -k^2 T_\alpha ' - \tau T_\alpha ' = - (k^2 + \tau^2) T_\alpha ' $$
Then it says that we obtain the IVP given by the equation $T_\alpha ''' = -(k^2 + \tau^2) T_\alpha' $ and the initial values $$T_\alpha(0) = (\frac{k}{\mu} , 0 , \frac{\tau}{\mu}) \\ N_\alpha(0) = (0,1,0) \\ B_\alpha (0) = (-\frac{\tau}{\mu} , 0 , \frac{k}{\mu})$$
where $\mu := \sqrt{k^2 + \tau^2}$ and then applies Cauchy's Theorems to conclude the result.
My question is, where do this values come from? It seems like the Frenet's relations and I understund that there are supposing a rigid movement to simplify but I do not see clearly why are this specific values.

@TedShifrin The author does not say anything more about the election of the initial values. That's the reason for me to ask.

@TedShifrin I do not know if I am understanding wrong but that sounds really weird to me. This is about knowing why those initial values ​​are chosen, not about obtaining the point at which those initial values ​​occur.

Weird that my comments have disappeared. Did someone flag them?  I'm saying that if you take the appropriate "standard" helix $\alpha(t)=(a\cos t,a\sin t,bt)$ with $a$ and $b$ chosen to give the correct curvature and torsion, then you will get those values.

@TedShifrin This is much easier to understand, thanks!
